# RecyclerView must not be null - within fragment

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to view a recyclerview within a fragment that immediately runs via MainActivity. I keep getting the 'itemList_hot must not be null' right on startup. I tried initializing it in the MainActivity but I must be doing something wrong. Very new to Android Studio but this is a roadblock I can't seem to figure out. Code below, thanks.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
        val viewPager: ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
        viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
        val tabs: TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs)
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

//error is here
        val recyclerView : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listItems_hot)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val dataManager = DataManager()
        recyclerView.adapter = HotRecyclerAdapter(this, dataManager.getData())
    }
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
    }
}
```

Fragment XML

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listItems_hot"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_list_hot">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Fragment code

```
class Tab1_Fragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false)
    }
}
```

Error code

```
findViewById(R.id.listItems_hot) must not be null
```

Comment: Your RecyclerView is in the Fragment - you're trying to find it in the Activity. You should set it up (find it, set a LayoutManager and Adapter) in the Fragment itself, say in ``onCreateView``. It's part of the Fragment so the Fragment should be responsible for it

Comment: So should I be just moving those 4 lines over to the fragment essentially?

Comment: Yeah, that and the Adapter code usually (since it's all part of the Fragment, as a component that does a particular thing). Depending on exactly what you're doing, you might need a way for the Activity and Adapter/Fragment to communicate with each other (like if data needs to be passed in to the Fragment, or clicking an item in the RecyclerView needs to call a function in the Activity - a ViewModel is the recommended standard way to coordinate that kind of thing

Comment: Now the context seems to be erroring out. Any idea why moving those lines over the context on LinearLayoutManager and my HotRecyclerAdapter would no longer be adequate in the fragment opposed to the mainactivity?

Comment: An ``Activity`` *is* a ``Context``, which is why you could pass ``this`` in the Activity. A ``Fragment`` *is not* a Context - you can use its ``context`` property (the same as ``getContext()`` - the result is nullable, i.e. ``Context?``) or call ``requireContext()`` (same thing but if the fragment isn't attached to a context, it throws an exception instead of returning null). Either is fine since in ``onCreate/onCreateView/onViewCreated`` ``onAttach`` has already been called, so you can expect to get a ``Context``: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle